# jQuery function on click with Node.js and Socket.IO

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've created a simple chat application as recommended (which works fine), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to launch a jQuery-function across web sockets with Socket.IO.

For example, I have a button to click:

```
<button id="button">
  Click me!
</button>
```

I would like my the button to execute a function when it's clicked:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  doSomething();
});
```

Here is an example of what I have on the client side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

function doSomething() {
    $('body').css({
         background: "red"
    });
}
```

Here is what I have on the server side (my server.js file) - I think this might be causing part of the issue:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
    connect = require ('connect');

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var commands = io.listen(app);

commands.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

    // Possibly insert handler here?

});
```

Just in case I wasn't clear on the purpose - I'd like that when the button is clicked, to have the body background of all connected clients turn red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to emit an event to your node.js/socket.io-server first on button clicked. Then on server-side you have to emit to all clients. On client side you have to listen on that server-side event. Also your server doesn't look very well.

Try something like this for example:

```
"use strict";

var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //senden an socket dass er verbunden ist
    //socket.emit('userOnline', {message: 'verbunden'});

    //Informationen vom User holen
    socket.on('changeBgColor', function (color) {
        console.log(color);
        socket.broadcast.emit('changeBgColorEveryWhere', color.color);
        socket.emit('changeBgColorEveryWhere', color.color);
    });
});

server.listen('3000');
```

For example on client-side:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io('ws://localhost:3000/');

            $(document).off('click', '#button').on('click', '#button', function (e) {
                console.log('click');

                socket.emit('changeBgColor', {color: 'red'});
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            socket.on('changeBgColorEveryWhere', function (color) {
                console.log(color);
                $('body').css('background', color);
            });
        </script>

        <button id="button">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try this, the page does not load at all, even with the server running.

Comment: @DRBC see my updated answer. I tested this on my local machine and it works fine.